# Compute Rational Exponent of Numbers

Tags: javascript

I stumbled upon an odd challenge recently which was about *pseudo-random number generators in JavaScript* to which
I'm grateful for the **Stack Overflow** community's response to solving the problem.

But now I *"hit another wall to climb over"* in terms of computing the exponent of numbers using non-integers.
I've gone through a few iterations of my approach to solving this and checked out a few solutions online with
the code I put out here being the closest solution I've got for this problem.

There is one small gap left before I overcome this challenge though and that is *multiplying the
exponent enough until it becomes an integer **at the beginning of the code*** (the part labelled `PROBLEM`).

This is a problem because simple evaluations such as `5.16 ^ .3333` overflow and compute the wrong thing.

My real question is what would be the way to solve for this.

```
// Compute base ^ exponent, where base and exponent are rationals numbers.
function pow(base, exponent) {
    var denominator = 1, numerator;

    // Convert from decimal to fraction
    // Multiply the exponent and denominator by 10 to convert them to integers
    while (exponent != parseInt(exponent)) {
        /* PROBLEM: This becomes infinity after multiplying a few times! */
        exponent *= 10;
        denominator *= 10
    }

    numerator = exponent;

    var t_x = numerator, t_y = denominator, temp;

    while (t_y) {
        temp = t_x % t_y;
        t_x = t_y;
        t_y = temp
    }

    // Simplify the numerator & denominator expressions to their lowest terms.
    numerator /= t_x;
    denominator /= t_x;

    var iterator = 1,
        nextResult, currentResult = 1,
        tolerance = 1,
        baseRaisedByExponentNumerator = base,
        nextResultRaisedByExponentDenominator;

    // NOTE: Might be the incorrect way of calculating this...
    for (iterator; iterator < numerator; iterator += 1)
        baseRaisedByExponentNumerator *= base;

    // Newton`s Method iterations
    while (tolerance > 1e-3) {
        nextResultRaisedByExponentDenominator = currentResult;

        for (iterator = 1; iterator < denominator; iterator += 1)
            nextResultRaisedByExponentDenominator *= currentResult;

        nextResult = currentResult - (nextResultRaisedByExponentDenominator - baseRaisedByExponentNumerator) / (denominator * (nextResultRaisedByExponentDenominator / currentResult));
        tolerance = ((nextResult - currentResult) / currentResult) * 100;
        (tolerance < 0) && (tolerance *= -1);
        currentResult = nextResult
    }

    // Return
    return nextResult
}
```

I am aware this is a specific question and not a feature-based question, but in my research into exponentiating
numbers with non-integers and having a JavaScript implementation of this I have found close to nothing.

The goal is understanding the algorithm behind a function like `Math.pow` which solves for problems like these; Or at least understand how browsers running JavaScript implements the `Math.pow` method.

So I do hope the community will be able to help solve this problem.

Comment: why not take `Math.pow` or logarithm?

Comment: I'd like to know how `Math.pow` was implemented in JavaScript but no such luck for me so far. It's like wanting to know how pseudo-random number generators are implemented in a programming language.

Comment: I'm not following this question... what's the problem of using `Math.pow(5.16,0.333)`?

Comment: The thing is, that `Math.pow` is not written in Javascript. The underlying engine has access to more precise numbers, code in js itself is limited onto numbers 64bit float precision. To get more precision you have to emulate bigger numbers with Big ints or Byte Arrays or strings etc.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado: The problem lies in understanding the algorithm, more than just having a magic function that computes an answer for me.

Comment: @Lapys in that case rephrase your question, making it clear that **this** is your actual problem.

Comment: @JonasWilms "*The underlying engine has access to more precise numbers*" - huh? Where would those numbers come from?

Comment: @bergi I'd guess that the js number is handed over to some c++ code, that does the computations with long, float, double etc. and then turn the result back into a js number and passing that back. correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @JonasWilms *"The thing is, that Math.pow is not written in Javascript"*... Using that reasoning, *nothing* is written in JS.

Comment: @JonasWilms Yes, the arguments are handed over to C++ code, but it stays a `double`.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado That's simply misinterpreting the point. `Math.pow` is implemented on the browser level in native code, there's still plenty of things written in JS. As for the original question, both Firefox and Chromium are open-source, you can freely read their implementations.

Comment: @nit I just tried to find it in v8, and I only found some native bindings to a `MathPow` function. However its unclear where that function originated from.